# React repeating optgroup label on droplist

Tags: reactjs, optgroup

[optgroup label is repeating on droplist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n93ej.png)

this is the dropdown

```
<Input
    id="period"
    name="period"
    type="select"
    required
    onChange={handleChange}>
    <option disabled selected>
        Please Select
    </option>
        {periodLists.map((item) => (
            <optgroup label={item.period_category}>
                <option
                    key={item.id}
                    value={item.period_name}>
                    {item.period_name}
                    </option>
                    </optgroup>
        ))}
</Input>
```

[this the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUtO3.png)

[I need display the droplist like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfo2R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a separate `optgroup` for each item.

You need to have two nested loops, an outer loop for the groups and an inner loop for the items.

```
<Input
  id="period"
  name="period"
  type="select"
  required
  onChange={handleChange}>
  <option disabled selected>
    Please Select
  </option>
  {
    [1, 2, 3].map((category) => (
      <optgroup label={category}>
      {
      periodLists.map.map((item) => (
          <option
            key={item.id}
            value={item.period_name}>
            {item.period_name}
          </option>
      ))
      }
      </optgroup>
    ))
  }
</Input>
```